# How to release an app with preloaded coreData ?

Tags: xcode, swift, core-data, osx-yosemite

I try to find the best way to release an app with some preoloaded data. 
I have an app that have 2 tables. I want to fill this tables with some data. The problem is that data is not only text info. 1 entity contains about 40 attributes (numbers, strings, transformable data), so to embedded that in code it's not a solution.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

1. Write a very small CLI OS X app that stands up your existing Core Data stack.
2. This CLI creates a pre-populated SQLite file in a known location.
3. Run this CLI as part of your build procedure
4. Include the created SQLite file as part of your app bundle
5. On launch, if the destination SQLite file does not exist (`NSFileManager` will tell you this); copy the SQLite file from your app bundle.
6. Launch as normal.

This makes the procedure scriptable and consistent.  It reuses your existing code structure to build the pre-populated database and lets you keep it up to date.

Comment: Of course, this only works for populating initial data. If you need to merge-in new data with data that might have been changed by the user, you’re going to need to do something slightly different.

Comment: If the user is going to be able to edit the data then I would keep the "ready only" data in the app bundle and create just a fresh store in the writeable area.  Then the read only can be updated at will.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I handle it:

I use the default setup, where the backing store for Core data is an SQL file.

I set up my app to set up the persistent store coordinator with the SQL file in the app's documents directory.

I build my pre-populated Core Data database on the simulator.

I then go to the app's documents directory on the sim and copy the sql file into the app's bundle.

At the beginning of my app's didFinishLaunching method in the app delegate,  I check to see if the Core data database's sql file exists in the documents directory. If not, I copy it from the bundle into the documents directory.

Then I invoke the code that creates the persistent store coordinator, which expects the sql file in the documents directory. On first launch, this is the initial file copied from the bundle. On subsequent launches, it's the working file in the documents directory that has the current data in it.

Comment: It is far better to write a tiny CLI and include it as part of your build process than to manually go into the simulator and grab the SQLite file.  Introducing a human component introduces errors.

Comment: I have already did that. But i want  find another way to do that, because i am panning to make an update, and i don't want to rewrite the data base again. User have posibility to write data, and if i do that, all data entered will lost.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra Meh. The "human component" is a once-and-done step performed by the developer. If you make a mistake in doing it, the app fails to run and you have to go fix it. That's true about countless steps in the development process.

Comment: @DuncanC Sorry, I agree with Marcus here. Human steps in your build process have too high a chance of going wrong. You should always automate your builds, either with external scripts and `xcodebuild`, or with build steps in Xcode itself.

Comment: @DuncanC it rarely stays a once and done.  What happens when you migrate to a new store?  Add new data?  There are multitudes of situations as the application matures which will cause that data to need to be refreshed.  It is never once and done unless the app never gets updated.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra, does CLI in your comment stand for Call Level Interface or Command Line Interface? And do you have any links to resources on how to go about that? My use of Core Data has been fairly light, and the app where I used the pre-baked SQL database has not required anything other than adding contents, so the approach was quite easy.

Comment: Command Line Interface.  Build a sub-xcode project and include it in your primary project.  From there the `maim.m` of the sub is where you put the creation code.  Not sure of an example online but it should be pretty straight-forward.  Really isn't much different than creating any other object.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm well familiar with command line tools. I just didn't understand what you were suggesting. I've build CLI tools into the build process that take .rtf files as source, convert them to archived NSAttributedStrings, and save them into the app bundle. That way I can include styled text files in my iOS project source and they come out the other end as string contents. Very handy way to deal with styled text in iOS.

Answer (score -1):

When the user first attempts to access the data, run a check to see if there are any objects in the persistent store by either executing a fetch request or getting the count of the objects in the persistent store.

If the results of the fetch request is nil, or the count of objects of the fetch request is 0, load data from some file (JSON, plist, XML) into Core Data by hand.

Comment: This is a very bad idea.  You are making the user pay the expense of pre-populating that database.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra I think you’ve exaggerated the badness of this approach somewhat. I prefer the CLI approach too, but for apps with small amounts of data this isn’t really any worse.

Comment: apps that start with small amounts of data become apps with large amounts of data really fast :)

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra Based on your last comment I think you misunderstood me. This process of initializing data only happens once, only during the very first launch of the application right after you install it from the app store.  

Any subsequent launches will not incur this overhead, because the precondition for this loading of data is that core data has nothing inside in the first place.

Comment: My point was that if you built another version of the app, add new fields, change the data, etc. then that pre-populated data is again needing to be constructed.  The construction of that pre-populated almost aways needs to be redone at some point in time and thus should be part of the build process.